# Postman test throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, postman

How do I make it work?

Goal: call a variable inside test script

Test script:

```
pm.test("shipment registration not allowed", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
 pm.expect(jsonData.results[0].errors.title).to.eql(pm.errors.get("shipmentRegistrationNotAllowed"));
});
```

The error:

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Comment: Wrong problem statement I suppose. I want to create a variable and assign it a value "Unknown Error" then assert response body that under Errors > Title has value of my variable, how would a test script look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where you have found `pm.errors.get` as a function that you can use but I don't believe it is something that is within Postman.

All the sandbox functions can be found here https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference

If you are just looking to assert that `jsonData.results[0].errors.title` equals a string value, you could just do this:

```
pm.test("shipment registration not allowed", () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json()
    pm.expect(jsonData.results[0].errors.title).to.eql(pm.globals.get("my_error_value"))
})
```

If you set a `global` variable you can reference in the test like this:

[image]

Comment: No, I want to assert that jsonData.results[0].errors.title equals a variable. Hope this makes sense